# Iota Light Wallet 2.5.7 Connection Refused

Tags: transaction, wallet

I am not able to get into my Iota account using Iota Light Wallet 2.5.7. I always get a Connection Refused error. The only responding node is the following but always get the Connection Refused error.

In 2019 I download and instaled https://trinity.iota.org

And send them some of my iotas everythin worked so I left it that way . Today I would like to carry over the rest of the funds and I cannot .

In 2019 on my wallet 2.5.7 balance is correct and I have seed ( 62 characters) today on old wallet 2.5.7 is connection refused and I can't log in . On new wallet trinity I have seed ( 81 characters ) and there is small ballance which I once transferred in the form of a test .

Answer (score 2):

problem solved . 62 characters 9999999999999999999 to 81 symbols.